# What is the architecture of laptop's blinking light. I have an Asus R558u laptop

Tags: windows-10, charging

When I put my laptop on sleep mode, the light starts to blink which is fine. But even after 10 hours of leaving it uncharged, the battery is retained very well. I want to know what is the architecture behind this power saving design.

Answer (score 2):

It is called ACPI.  10 hours is nothing.. I have a tiny laptop that sat in a sleep state for 22 days before running out of power.  Even then, the operating system used the last little bit of power to hibernate so I STILL didn't lose any data.

In addition to the hardware allowing it (ACPI), the operating systems keep getting better and better at power management.

BTW, the blinking LED takes almost no power.. keeping the ram powered is where much of the battery goes when it is in a sleep state.

Read about ACPI  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)